# Proving statements about connected graph related to its subgraphs.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a connected graph. For a vertex $x$ of $G$ we denote by $G-x$ 
>   the graph formed by removing $x$ and all edges incident on $x$ from $G$. 
>   $G$ is said to be good if there are at least two distinct
>   vertices $x, y$ in $G$ such that both $G - x$ and $G - y$ are
>   connected.
>
> 1. Show that for any subgraph $H$ of $G$, $H$ is good if and only if $G$ is good.
> 2. Given a good graph, devise a linear time algorithm to find two such vertices.
> 3. Show that there exists a graph $H$ such that we cannot find three distinct vertices $u1, u2, u3$ such that each of $G - u_1, G - u_2$
>      and $G - u_3$ is connected.

I'm asking here instead of CS stackexchange because I'm primarily interested in (1) and (3) rather than (2).

---

I can't seem to get anywhere with this problem; I do not see how it is possible for **all** subgraphs of a good graph $G$ to be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 isn't (quite) true. In fact *every* connected graph with at least two vertices is good. (Hint: consider a spanning tree of $G$.) But obviously for any $G$ you can take a single-vertex subgraph $H$, which is not good. Presumably what is meant is "for any connected spanning subgraph $H$ ..."

The hint above should also help with part 2. For part 3, let $G$ be a path.

Comment: Thanks! The hint makes solving 2 and 3 nearly trivial. But even with the revised interpretation of the "subgraph", one can clearly create a spanning subgraph $H$ of a good graph $G$ such that $H$ has more than one connected component-thus $H$ is not good. So 1 isn't true after all, right?

Comment: Well, the question doesn't even define what it means for a non-connected graph to be good, but yes, I think it only makes sense if it's talking about connected subgraphs.